# Boolean comparison in Pandas Groupby extremely slow with mysteriously appearing MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multi-index

I am making some boolean comparisons within a pandas groupby and am experiencing over a 3x slowdown. It is a lot of data, but I don't think these boolean checks should be this slow. After I run the code, my DataFrame mysteriously has a new MultiIndex it did not have before, so I am thinking this is where the slowdown is coming from.

```
def my_func(group):
    uncanceled_values = group[['t1_values','final_values']].max(axis=1)
    group['t1_values_total'] = group['t1_values'].sum()
    group['final_values_total'] = uncanceled_values.sum()
    group['t1_values_share'] = group['t1_values'] / group['t1_values_total']
    group['t1_to_final_values_share'] = np.where(uncanceled_values.sum() > group['t1_values'].sum(),
                                               ((group['final_values'] - group['t1_values']) / 
                                                (group['final_values_total'] - group['t1_values_total'])),
                                               0)
    group['t1_values_rank'] = group['t1_values'].rank(ascending = False)
    group['t1_to_final_values_rank'] = group['t1_to_final_values_share'].rank(ascending = False)
    if (group['final_values_total'] < 2000.0).any() or (group['t1_values_share'] == 0.0).any():
        return
    else:
        return group
```

I apply this function over the groupby like so:

```
df= df.groupby('id').apply(my_func)
```

But then I need to drop the MultiIndex it produces:

```
df= df.droplevel('id')
```

I am wondering if the fact that I don't return the group under those 2 conditions makes pandas have a hard time piecing the df back together so it has to multiindex.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Comment: The MultiIndex is created because of your return. If you always returned `group`, then your apply doesn't really aggregate, it calculates within group values and returns a result that is the same length as the original, so the `apply` would use the original Index. Because the apply sometimes returns nothing, when pandas tries to put together the result it has to decide _how_ it should join and label these different returns. As a result, it puts the group keys  ('id') as an additional level of the Index, and since your apply returns a DataFrame it's added as a level to your existing index.

Comment: @ALollz Indeed, adding group.loc[:] = np.nan
        return group fixed the issue, by making sure we always return the group, I just marked them with NaNs to be dropped later. Thanks!